# XMPP accepting presence request

Tags: php, xml, client, xmpp

How can I confirm a presence request? I am connecting to external (not mine) XMPP server with my [XMPP PHP client library](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/xmpp-php). XMPP server in turn handles Facebook communication. So the current flow is:

```
client lib -> XMPP server -> Facebook
```

I can issue a subscription request by doing a

```
<presence from="my-client" to="facebook-user" type="subscribe"/>
```

The response from server I get looks like this:

```
<iq type="set" id="xx-xxxxxx" to="my-client/resource">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
        <item jid="facebook-user" ask="subscribe" subscription="none"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

Client in this case are my JID credentials with which I can connect to XMPP server, and Facebook user is my personal Facebook account.

Is it possible to accept such a request?

Comment: It looks like you correctly requested presence but haven't received request to confirm. Take a look at specification [Managing Presence Subscriptions](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#sub).